# Python mysqldb db.commit() not working

Tags: python, mysql-python, gevent

I have some code like this

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="domains")
cursor = db.cursor()

def check_urls(res):
    pool = Pool(25)
    for row in res:
        pool.spawn(fetch, row[0], row[1])
    pool.join()

def fetch(*args):
    """code trimmed for brevity"""
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE com SET http_status=%s, is_checked=1 WHERE id=%s""",
                  (output.get('http_status', ""), id))


for _ in xrange(10000):
    cursor.execute("SELECT domain, id FROM com WHERE is_checked IS NULL LIMIT 100")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    check_urls(result)
    db.commit()


cursor.close()
db.close()
```

`My program get stuck at db.commit()`. No values updated in the database. Can someone tell me whats wrong?.

**Please note:**
My `check_urls` function has a `for loop` and each loop has one mysql update query.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does "stuck at db.commit()" mean? Is the program stuck or do you mean that part doesn't happen?

Comment: It appears as though you might be spawning 25,000 threads and joining the results back together just before the commit. Are you sure the commit is the problem? It's not that likely...

Comment: @yuvi No i'm not getting any errors. I checked my MySQL error logs. No errors. I mean its running only the first loop. Even that first loop no values get updated in the database

Comment: @Ben 25000 threads? I'm selecting only 100 domains and passing it into the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should move your db.commit() into fetch function after cursor.execute. Another way you may use "global" keyword with cursor. Or, third way, just make cursor as parameter of functions.